# searching nested object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like one below and and I want to retrieve "SubscriptionId" for the "SubscriptionScheme='daily' if exists or return  false. I am a bit struggling combining filter and find methods. Thanks in advance.

```
    {
      [ 
       {
        "SubscriptionId": "s1 ",
        "SubscriptionType": "User",
        "SubscriptionFieldList": 
           {
             "SubscriptionFieldInfo": [
               {
                 "SubscriptionMethod": "Direct",
                 "SubscriptionScheme": "Monthly"
               }
             ]
          }
       },
       {
       "SubscriptionId": "s2 ",
       "SubscriptionType": "User",
       "SubscriptionFieldList": {
       "SubscriptionFieldInfo": [
          {
            ":SubscriptionMethod": "Direct",
            "SubscriptionScheme": "daily"
          }
        ]
      }
     }
   ]
  }
```

So expected result is `"s2 "`.

Comment: I don't understand your goal. What do you want to return if the subscription scheme is 'daily'? What is your desired end result?

Comment: and why is `SubscriptionFieldInfo` an array to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```js
var arr = [ 
       {
        "SubscriptionId": "s1 ",
        "SubscriptionType": "User",
        "SubscriptionFieldList": 
           {
             "SubscriptionFieldInfo": [
               {
                 "SubscriptionMethod": "Direct",
                 "SubscriptionScheme": "Monthly"
               }
             ]
          }
       },
       {
       "SubscriptionId": "s2 ",
       "SubscriptionType": "User",
       "SubscriptionFieldList": {
       "SubscriptionFieldInfo": [
          {
            ":SubscriptionMethod": "Direct",
            "SubscriptionFieldInfo": "daily"
          }
        ]
      }
     }
   ];
   
var obj = arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.SubscriptionFieldList.SubscriptionFieldInfo.some(x=>x.SubscriptionFieldInfo === "daily");
});

if(obj !== undefined && obj.length == 1){
    console.log(obj[0].SubscriptionId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and want to add a bit more. I want to return "SubscriptionId" for "SubscriptionType"="User" and  "SubscriptionMethod"="Direct". I am new to this and can you please help me to write a function to do this? Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. You mean that you want to return `SubscriptionId`, when `SubscriptionType` is "User"? I don't get you completely. However if that's the case it's pretty straightforward, what you should do. I would suggest you put some effort and provided you don't make it, ask again stating what is the problem. This way you would get the most out of it. Otherwise, you would have a solution, which might you don't understand. For instance, from the above answer, If I were you I would read about `filter`, `some`, arrow function, `x=>x...`. Having understand this, I would try from the start :)